# Can't send emails from my local machine to google

Tags: php, linux, email, postfix-mta

Why isn't the following working?

```
<?php

    mail('oshirowanen@gmail.com', 'some text here', 'some text here');

?>
```

access.log shows:

`127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jan/2013:08:46:52 +0000] "GET /test_mail.php HTTP/1.1" 200 294 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/12.04 Chromium/20.0.1132.47 Chrome/20.0.1132.47 Safari/536.11"`

error.log shows:

`nothing`

I have also tried the following from the terminal:

```
echo 'body' | sendmail recipient@example.net
```

and nothing.

and the mail.log shows:

```
Jan 16 08:57:24 ubuntu postfix/smtp[4081]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4001:c02::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
```

I don't get an email in my inbox or spam box.

Comment: The most interesting bit would be what your mail.log says and if the `mail()` method returns either true/false.

Comment: -1, no research effort.  There are two and a half billion dupes of this question on SO, most of which come down to either server misconfiguration or spam filters.  Switch to a third-party library that uses SMTP so you can verify that the mail was actually delivered, and go from there.  Swiftmailer, PHPMailer, PEAR's Mail class, etc... *anything* other than PHP `mail()`.

Comment: I've added a little extra info to my question.

Comment: Thank you!  You've turned this into an answerable question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working using the following:

```
sudo apt-get install sendmail
```

Edit your php.ini to uncomment sendmail - mine was located in

```
/etc/php5/apache2/
```

put

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

Save changes and restart apache.

Answer (score 7):

> `postfix/smtp[4081]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4001:c02::1a]:25: Network is unreachable`

It looks like you're using Postfix with [IPv6 support enabled](http://www.postfix.org/IPV6_README.html), but you are not on an IPv6 network that is connected to the internet at large, or have firewall rules preventing the connection.

The most simple troubleshooting method will be to edit `main.cf` and change `inet_protocols` to `ipv4` instead of whatever it's currently set to.  Be sure to completely restart the Postfix service after making this change.  The linked documentation page will have more information on the implications of having IPv6 support enabled.

If you still can't connect after dropping down to IPv4, look for firewall rules between your system and the internet.

I still want to *actively encourage you* to *not* use PHP's `mail()` function.  `mail()` does *not* guarantee delivery.  All it guarantees it that it *tried* to hand off mail to *something* behind the scenes.  It gives you no clues when things go wrong.  Instead, please use a third-party mail library like [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) in combination with a known-working SMTP server.  These libraries make it far, far more obvious when something goes wrong while sending, and you get tremendously useful features to boot.

Comment: And *why* is the network unreachable? If ifconfig reports an inet6-Address FE80:..., then here's the explanation: http://serverfault.com/questions/424922/how-to-get-ipv6-running-properly